A list of tuples from dictionary where values are lists
I need to convert a dictionary in a form {1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2: ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']} to a list of tuples in a form [(1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (2, 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h')].
When I try that:
dictionary = {1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2: ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']}

list_of_tuples = [(k, v) for k, v in dictionary.items()]

I get
list_of_tuples = [(1, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), (2, ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h'])]

and I need
list_of_tuples = [(1, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), (2, 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h')]


Try
list_of_tuples = [(k, *v) for k, v in dictionary.items()]

*v unpacks v.

Thank you so much for such a quick reponse and so efficient answer! I solved my issue!

Glad it helped! You can hit the checkmark to mark this question as solved.

This works for me too:
list_of_tuples = [(key,*dictionary[key]) for key in dictionary]


This makes an unnecessary dictionary lookup (dictionary[key]). Using the .items() method you get key and value in one shot.

Good point @MannyC
However, out of curiosity, I used the time module and compared both lines separately, each for 1000 times.
The first line used 0.00146 sec and the second used 0.00097 sec.
Interesting results I believe are worth being shared.

I think the difference becomes appreciable when dictionary is very big with many keys.
